# SplitView and Back Button Navigation - UWP - C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am currently learning C# in UWP environment. I have a test app which is having a bit of the problem as described in [Splitview with frame and navigating to another page, back button does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355257/splitview-with-frame-and-navigating-to-another-page-back-button-does-not-work).
But the my code is a little different from the above page.

My `App.xaml.cs` has the following code:

```
namespace Testing
{
/// <summary>
/// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
/// </summary>
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        //NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }



            // Place the frame in the current Window
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
            //Window.Current.Content = new SplitShellPage(rootFrame);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
        if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
        {
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }

            Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += App_BackRequested;

            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
    private void App_BackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
            return;

        // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
        // already been handled .
        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }


}

}
```

If I use `Window.Current.Content = new SplitShellPage(rootFrame);` as in place of `Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;` the `SplitView` works but the back button does not work. If I use the second line then `SplitView` doesn't work but back navigation works.

I even tried setting my launch page to `SplitView` page as `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SplitShellPage), e.Arguments);` but that causes the application to stop at runtime and the application doesn't start.

The other pages with code are as:

SplitShellPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Testing.Pages
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class SplitShellPage : Page
 {

    public SplitShellPage(Frame frame)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        shell_splitview.Content = frame;
        (shell_splitview.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }

    private void hamburger_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        shell_splitview.IsPaneOpen = !shell_splitview.IsPaneOpen;
    }
 }
}
```

This method of work I found when searching on google to make the `NavigationPane` work in all the pages and it does work in all the pages just without the `Back Navigation`.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Testing
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    }


    private void Settings_Flyout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
    }
 }
}
```

I have done some searches on google but nothing makes sense because they use some other methods and things get more complicated.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong here and how to make it right. Thanks.

P.S. Let me know if I need to also share the `XAML` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use Window.Current.Content = new SplitShellPage(rootFrame); as in place of Window.Current.Content = rootFrame; the SplitView works but the back button does not work

In this situation, the frame currently you are using is `shell_splitview.Content`.
Because you are using this code for navigating `(shell_splitview.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MainPage));`. So in `App.xaml.cs` the method `App_BackRequested` method try to get the `Window.Current.Content as Frame` for navigating, the back button will not work.

The solution is provided by the demo in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355257/splitview-with-frame-and-navigating-to-another-page-back-button-does-not-work) you reference, to add the `BackRequested` event handle in the page which defined the SplitView. Update your code in `SplitShellPage.xaml.cs` as follows the back button will work.

```
public SplitShellPage(Frame frame)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    shell_splitview.Content = frame;
    (shell_splitview.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += SplitShellPage_BackRequested;
}

private void SplitShellPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame myFrame = shell_splitview.Content as Frame;
    if (myFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        myFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

> If I use the second line then SplitView doesn't work but back navigation works.

In this situation, we even did not access the `SplitShellPage`, and didn't access the `SplitView`. It is just a implemention of back button between two simple page. It works and has noting relationship with the content of `SplitView`.

The key point for this issue is to clear which frame you are using for navigating now , rootFrame(`Window.Current.Content`) or the `SplitViewContent` frame. And navigating back with back button need the same frame.

You can download the demo from the thread you referenced for further testing.  And more details please reference [Back button navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt465734.aspx).

Comment: Alright, I shall give it a try and be back with how it goes.